# How can I Create this configuration programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an WCF and I'm needing to create this configuration dinamically because my 
app.config never changes in client machines.

Any body help?

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- REST -->
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint name="json" address="http://localhost:8080/json"
               binding="webHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
               behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
               contract="ServiceReference.ServiceClientContract" />
</client>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "create this configuration dynamically"? just coping the data as it is?

Comment: Could you please elaborate at what point you want to create this configuration ?

Comment: In my code. Not in app.config

Comment: Let me understand, you want to create a file via code, and which the content of the file is what? What do you want to include inside the file?

Comment: The WCF config wraps up several important WCF concepts. I'd recomend reading this documentation before taking any other steps.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx

Comment: @ISun, I Want To create a HttpBinding and Endpoint via Code with these configurations, including my Behavior (name "restBehavior") showed above...

Answer (score 2):

Most WCF elements in the config file have a corresponding class or property that can be set in code (which is presumably what you meant by "dynamically"?) For example, 'endpointBehaviors' can be accessed through the Behaviors property of the ServiceEndpoint class:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/Simple");
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(ICalculator),
    new WSHttpBinding(),
    "CalculatorServiceObject");

endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());

Console.WriteLine("List all behaviors:");
foreach (IEndpointBehavior behavior in endpoint.Behaviors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Behavior: {0}", behavior.ToString());
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.behaviors.aspx

Searching any of the elements your are interested in configuring in MSDN should be enough to get you started.